# KendoUI MVC grid doesn't show data for pages except first page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui-mvc

I have a KendoUI MVC grid as follows:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MonitoringVm>()
          .Name("monitoringGrid")
          .Columns(columns =>
          {
              columns.Bound(c => c.RecordDateTime).Title("Date Time").Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy hh:mmtt}").Width(149);
              columns.Bound(c => c.SourceEndpointName).Title("Source").Width(100).Sortable(true);
              columns.Bound(c => c.DestinationEndpointName).Title("Destination").Width(100);
              columns.Bound(c => c.TagName).Title("Tag").Width(120);
              columns.Bound(c => c.ErrorDescription).Title("Description");
              columns.Bound(c => c.LogTransferErrorId).Title("Retry")
                  .ClientTemplate("<div style='text-align: center;'><button class='k-button k-primary' type='button' onclick=\"javascript: retryRequest(this);\">Retry</button></div>")
                  .HeaderTemplate("<div style='text-align: center;'>Retry</div>")
                  .Width(50);
              columns.Bound(c => c.LogTransferErrorId).Title("Delete")
                  .ClientTemplate("<div style='text-align: center;'><img src='/Content/Images/iconfinder_bin.png' onclick=\"javascript: confirmArchiveError('#:data.LogTransferErrorId#');\" class='archive-error'/></div>")
                  .HeaderTemplate("<div style='text-align: center;'>Delete</div>")
                  .Width(50);
          }
          )
          .Pageable()
          .Sortable(sortable => sortable.AllowUnsort(true))
          .ClientDetailTemplateId("template")
          .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
              .Ajax()
              .PageSize(25)
              .ServerOperation(true)
              .Read(read => read.Action("ReadErrorRecords", "Monitoring"))
          )
          .Events(events => events.DataBound("dataBound")))
```

The corresponding controller is as follows:

```
private readonly JsonHttpClient _client;
public JsonResult ReadErrorRecords([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        var urlEndpoint = $"Monitor/ErrorRecords?page={request.Page}&pageSize={request.PageSize}";
        var response = _client.Get<MonitoringVmResponse>(urlEndpoint);

        DataSourceResult result = response.Results.ToDataSourceResult(request);
        result.Total = response.Count ?? 0;
        return Json(result);
    }
```

When I navigate to different pages, the above controller method is called. In debugger, I observed that I receive the correct data and the same is returned from the controller.

On the UI, for subsequent pages after the first page, data is not shown.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're doing pagination twice.

Let's say you issued a request for the second page. 
I suppose that your `_client.Get<MonitoringVmResponse>(urlEndpoint)` would return records from 26 to 50. 
But later you're calling `response.Results.ToDataSourceResult(request)` which also applies `.Skip(25)` and `.Take(25)` internally so all of your items from the previous call will be skipped and no data will be returned to your view.

I guess there are 2 possible workarounds for this:

1. Instead of `.ToDataSourceResult(request)` it's possible to use other Kendo extension methods like `GroupBy`, `OrderBy`, `Where` etc.
2. It's possible to "fool" `.ToDataSourceResult(request)` method by providing a value 1 as a `request.Page`:

```cs
    var response = _client.Get<MonitoringVmResponse>(urlEndpoint);
    request.Page = 1;
    DataSourceResult result = response.Results.ToDataSourceResult(request);
```

Comment: Yeah, the second workaround worked well!

The third workaround would be not to use the `ToDataSourceResult(request)` method at all. Create your own `DataSourceResult` object and then write your own ordering logic like [this](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/binding/custom-binding#set-custom-server-binding)